# 2005 Pontiac Grand Prix GT Radio Theftlock

Tags: audio, pontiac, security, gm, theft-prevention

Blew the bulb in my stock radio, picked up another radio from the junk yard, and of course there's the theftlock (I should've known). I've read about being able to get a code by holding down various button combinations, but I'm not having any luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look it up. It is specific to your car make and model. Or ask a dealer if you do not know how to do it or want to do it.

Comment: Why not transfer the bulb from the junk yard radio to yours? Or have you now blown the codes for both radios ?

Comment: @SolarMike - That's a great suggestion.

Comment: I'm going to try transferring the bulb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC There are no button combinations to retrieve a code. The theft lock system has to be reset with a scantool and a new VIN has to be written to the new module. Anyone with a Tech2 or similar scantool can do this.